# Change cube rotation speed through input (threejs)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using the Threejs tutorial to make a javascript cube. This worked.
Now I want a number input on my page to change the speed at which the cube rotates (X and Y axis) but I can't figure out how. Anyone able to help me with this?

I have tried using number and text inputs but I'm sure it has to do with my javascript (I'm not that great)

HTML

```
<ul>
        <li>Color cube: <input type="text" id="colorCube" placeholder=""></li><br>
        <li>Rotation X: <input type="number" id="rotationCubeX" placeholder=""></li><br>
        <li>Rotation Y: <input type="number" id="rotationCubeY" placeholder=""></li><br>
        <li>Change: <input id="submitColor" value="Submit" type="button"></li>
</ul>
```

This is where I want to change the rotation in (the color works)

JS

```
var cube = (function(){
  my = {};

  var cube;
  var xSpeed = parseFloat(document.getElementById('rotationCubeX').value);
  var ySpeed = parseFloat(document.getElementById('rotationCubeY').value);

  // Function to change color
  my.color = function(value){
    cube.material.color.set(value);
  }


  // Generate Cube

  my.generate = function(colorCube, rotationCubeX, rotationCubeY) {
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var width = 1280;
    var height = 505;
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, width / height, 0.1, 1000);
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

    renderer.setSize(width, height);
    renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true; //Shadow
    renderer.shadowMapSoft = true; // Shadow
    renderer.shadowMapType = THREE.PCFShadowMap; //Shadow

    document.getElementById('projects').appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    // Define Shape Object
    geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
    material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ // Required For Shadows
      color: colorCube,
      specular: 0x000000,
      shininess: 100
    });

    //Cube
    cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    cube.position.y = 0.8;
    cube.castShadow = true;
    cube.receiveShadow = true;
    scene.add(cube);
    camera.position.z = 3;
    camera.position.y = 1.8;
    camera.position.x = 0;

    // Floor
    var floorGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(100, 100, 20, 20);
    var floorMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
      color: 0xecebec,
      specular: 0x000000,
      shininess: 0
    });

    var floor = new THREE.Mesh(floorGeometry, floorMaterial);
    floor.rotation.x = -0.5 * Math.PI;
    floor.receiveShadow = true;
    scene.add(floor);

    // Lights
    // Ambient light for general illumination
    var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x090909);
    scene.add(ambientLight);

    // Spotlight for specific illumination
    var spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xAAAAAA);
    spotLight.position.set(2, 3, 3);
    spotLight.castShadow = true;
    spotLight.shadowBias = 0.0001;
    spotLight.shadowDarkness = 0.2;
    spotLight.shadowMapWidth = 2048; // Shadow Quality
    spotLight.shadowMapHeight = 2048; // Shadow Quality
    scene.add(spotLight);

    // Render Loop
    function render() {
      requestAnimationFrame(render);
      cube.rotation.x += xSpeed; // spin cube
      cube.rotation.y += ySpeed; //spin cube
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
    //window.addEventListener('click', onDocumentMouseDown, false);
    render();
  }


//function onDocumentMouseDown(event) {

  // Welcome to the exciting world of raycasting !
  // First let's get some mouse coordinates:
  //mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
  //mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
  // This is basically converting 2d coordinates to 3d Space:
  //raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
  // And checking if it intersects with an array object
  //var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects([cube]);



  // And finally change the color:
  // if (intersects.length > 0) {
  //   intersects[0].object.material.color.setHex(Math.random() * 0xffffff);
  // }
//}

return my;
}());
```

This is where the starting rotation is added to the cube (if I were to change the 0.001 to rotationCubeX the cube doesnt spawn)

Main.JS

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  cube.generate('blue', 0.001, 0.005);

  document.getElementById("submitColor").onclick = function() {
    cube.color(document.getElementById('colorCube').value);
    // cube.color(document.getElementById('rotationCube').value);
    xSpeed = parseFloat(document.getElementById('rotationCubeX').value);
    ySpeed = parseFloat(document.getElementById('rotationCubeY').value);
  };

});
```

This is my main.js where I call the functions

I made this with great help of the provided Threejs code but I am stuck now.

Comment: You don't have `document.getElementById('rotationCube')` but `document.getElementById('rotationCubeX')` and you call cube.color() with the value of rotationCube

Comment: I changed that, stupid that I didn't see that. I do get an error that cube.rotation.x.set(value) isn't a function.

Comment: In your JS you are setting `my.rotation = function...` twice. I think it should be `my.rotation.x = function()` or `my.rotationX = function()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment your cube spins using the hardcoded values **0.001** and **0.005** inside the **render()** function.
To be able to change those values you need two global variables instead.

First determine the initial speed directly using the input element's value property:

```
<ul>
  <li>Color cube: <input type="text" id="colorCube" placeholder=""></li><br>
  <li>Rotation X: <input type="number" id="rotationCubeX" placeholder="" value="0.001"></li><br>
  <li>Rotation Y: <input type="number" id="rotationCubeY" placeholder="" value="0.005"></li><br>
  <li>Change: <input id="submitColor" value="Submit" type="button"></li>
</ul>
```

Create two global variables and get the values from the input element:

```
var xSpeed = parseFloat(document.getElementById('rotationCubeX').value);
var ySpeed = parseFloat(document.getElementById('rotationCubeY').value);
```

**parseFloat()** is used because the value returned from the property is a string.

Update the variables as soon as the submit button is clicked:

```
document.getElementById("submitColor").onclick = function() {
  cube.color(document.getElementById('colorCube').value);
  cube.color(document.getElementById('rotationCube').value);
  xSpeed = parseFloat(document.getElementById('rotationCubeX').value);
  ySpeed = parseFloat(document.getElementById('rotationCubeY').value);
};
```

Finally use the value of the global variabels inside the render function:

```
function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  cube.rotation.x += xSpeed; // spin cube
  cube.rotation.y += ySpeed; //spin cube
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

Here's a live example. Please make sure to click **Submit** after chaning values using the up/down arrows.

```js
var camera, scene, renderer;
var cube;
var width = 400;
var height = 300;
var xSpeed = parseFloat(document.getElementById('rotationCubeX').value);
var ySpeed = parseFloat(document.getElementById('rotationCubeY').value);

function init() {
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, width / height, 1, 1000);
  camera.position.z = 400;
  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(200, 200, 200);

  cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial());
  scene.add(cube);

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
  });
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(width, height);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  cube.rotation.x += xSpeed;
  cube.rotation.y += ySpeed;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

init();
animate();

document.getElementById("submitColor").onclick = function() {
  xSpeed = parseFloat(document.getElementById('rotationCubeX').value);
  ySpeed = parseFloat(document.getElementById('rotationCubeY').value);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Color cube: <input type="text" id="colorCube" placeholder=""></li><br>
  <li>Rotation X: <input type="number" id="rotationCubeX" placeholder="" value="0.001" step="0.01"></li><br>
  <li>Rotation Y: <input type="number" id="rotationCubeY" placeholder="" value="0.005" step="0.01"></li><br>
  <li>Change: <input id="submitColor" value="Submit" type="button"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hey man, your code makes sense but I guess I'm still missing something. I'm getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
    at HTMLInputElement.document.getElementById.onclick (main.js:6) which refers to this line: cube.color(document.getElementById('rotationCube').value); Also I feel like this: ```
  my.rotation = function(value){
    cube.rotation.x.set(value);
  }

  my.rotation = function(value){
    cube.rotation.y.set(value);
  }
``` still isnt correct

Comment: I changed everything to the way you described in your comment by the way so there is no difference in that :)

Comment: You get an `Uncaught TypeError:...` because there is no element with the ID of rotationCube, so get rid of the line `cube.color(document.getElementById('rotationCube').value);` Also the `my.rotation= function` definitions are useless. Get rid of 'em too! =)

Comment: I did that but it somehow still doesn't change the speed at which the cube rotates? Is there a way I could perhaps send the code in total or maybe I am using the <input type="number"> wrong? It doesn't give errors this time

Comment: I've included a demo to my answer above. I'm sure it'll help you.

Comment: Is it possible for me to send some screenshots of my code to you? I don't want to be annoying but I did like everything you told me and I cant get the rotation speed to change :c

Comment: Really weird - even if you compare your code to the live demo it doesn't work? Any messages in the console? By the way - you can update your original question with the code (just hit the tiny edit button).

Comment: I added the entire Javascript. There is probably a really stupid thing I'm not seeing but I really don't understand what's going on

Comment: Well not really stupid. You put the definition `var xSpeed=` and `var ySpeed` inside the `var cube = (function(){ ... }` code block - which means this variables are just accessible from within. Later on you try to change them inside the callback function for `document.getElementById("submitColor").onclick` but it's outside of this scope. The fix is rather easy: just move var xSpeed=... var ySpeed=... to the beginning of your main.js file. Also make sure your li elements have a default value e.g. `<li>Rotation X: <input type="number" id="rotationCubeX" placeholder="" value="0.001">`